# How to parse next node attribute after keypress (Java DOM Parser)

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom, keypress

At the moment I am creating some dialogues for the game I'm working on.
I want to do this by XML parsing.

I got the parsing working in the system.out.println, but it prints all results from the XML.

**XML DOC:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<cutscene>
    <conversation id="1">
            <name>Rubeus Hagrid</name>
            <line>Sorry about the door..</line>
    </conversation>
    <conversation id="2">
            <name>Herman Duffeling</name>
            <line>I want you to leave immediately, this is my home!</line>
    </conversation>
        <conversation id="3">
            <name>Rubeus Hagrid</name>
            <line>Oh, shut up..</line>
        </conversation>
</cutscene>
```

**Java source code:**

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import java.io.File;

public class ReadXMLFile {

  public static void main(String argv[]) {

    try {

    File fXmlFile = new File("Resources/XML/conversations.xml");
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

    NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("conversation");

    for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

        Node nNode = nList.item(temp);

        if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

            Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

            System.out.println(eElement.getAttribute("id"));
            System.out.println(eElement.getElementsByTagName("name").item(0).getTextContent() + ": ");
            System.out.println(eElement.getElementsByTagName("line").item(0).getTextContent());

            System.out.println("---------------------------");
        }
    }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

}
```

**The code prints the following:**

```
1
Rubeus Hagrid: 
Sorry about the door..
---------------------------
2
Herman Duffeling: 
I want you to leave immediately, this is my home!
---------------------------
3
Rubeus Hagrid: 
Oh, shut up..
---------------------------
```

**And this is what I want to do:**

```
 1
 Rubeus Hagrid: 
 Sorry about the door..
 ---------------------------
```

When you click on a key here (I was thinking about the Enter key), you need to see the next item, so that would be number 2.

Please help me out!

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is looking into `Xpath` and how to work with it in Java.
In one line, `XPath` is a node-addressing language that allows you to retrieve an appropriate node or a set of nodes from the XML file.

Since you have an `id` attribute which increases by 1 for every progress in conversation, you may want to retrieve the proper node using `XPath` based on `id` attribute. Just keep a track of the id attribute as an `int` which you increase on every key press. Then, based on the value, get the node.

Your `XPath` query would look like:

```
//conversation[@id=2]
```

this selects the `conversation` tag where the `id` attribute is `2`.
Now, to get the name and line,

```
//conversation[@id=2]/line
```

and

```
//conversation[@id=2]/name
```

Comment: I take it as logic that you that create a functions that activates when you press "Enter" and then does: id="current + 1" every time on the keypress?

Comment: I am assuming it is GUI based. So you need a key listener. In command line, yes you need to look for enter key to be pressed. You got the logic right.